# Сделать чужое окно растягиваемым

Tags: winapi

Как сделать? `SIZEBOX` у окна не активен.
Пробовал так, не получается, приложение зависает...

```
 SetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE)
                &WS_SIZEBOX);
 SetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE)
                &~WS_SYSMENU & WS_SIZEBOX);
```

`SetWindowPos` отлично срабатывает, но всё же хотелось бы чтобы мышкой можно было менять.

Comment: [SetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(wnd, GWL_STYLE) | WS_SIZEBOX);](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но так я уже пробовал, окно подвисает просто напросто...

Comment: Извиняюсь, всё заработало, был невнимателен. Благодарю за помощь.